# Publish limit on Facebook's Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using the Graph API for a while.

One feature of my application is that it allows a user to post a message on their friends walls (dont worry it is not spam).

Anyway...there is a limit on the API and it will only allow a certain number of posts before failing. I've read on the facebook bucket allocation limits but my app's limit has not moved. It was 26 when i created the app. It is still 26 even though there are about 20 users.

What can I do to increase my pulish limit?

And I promise this app is not used for anything spam related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those wanting an answer to this question: The posting limit is dynamic.

Facebook has implemented a bucket allocation system whereby each token/profile is given a set amount of posts per day (currently at 20-24). This allocation can go up or down based on the "affinity" your users show towards your application.

From Facebook:

> Based on the affinity users show for your apps use of Facebook Platform through their interactions, your app is allocated certain abilities and limits. This is the functionality currently allocated to your app. These values will change over time depending on how users interact with your app. All integration points have a set of limit values and the threshold bucket column tells you which of these limits buckets your app is in for that integration point. Bucket 1 is the smallest allocation bucket.

If more people like/use your application, your posting limit will be increased. On the other hand, if you do not have traction or many people are marking posts from your app as spam, then the limit will be decreased.

You can find the current limit of your application by going to the App Page > View Insights > Diagnostics.

You can find the current limit under the Allocations header.

Comment: This is outdated and doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: @ArturBodera What applies now?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, FB doesn't clearly tell about this limit. The message quoted above is also nowhere to be found. The closest resources I came across on FB's website are these:

- [This](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/83/) one briefly talks about the allocation system but doesn't get into details
- Also, I found a related FB REST [API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.getAllocation/) : But be aware, that this is REST API and should get deprecated soon.